# PHP, MySQL stored procedure not storing data as expected

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

There does not seem to be a repeat of this question and I feel this should be a simple fix.
I have tested the stored procedure and when adding the parameters it works fine, 
I have also tested a simple SQL statement which also works as expected. 
However, when I try to pass my variables into the statement, I get a "Zero results using SQL:" I have also tried to do this as just a prepared statement or as just pure SQL with my variables, but again it never stores anything in the database.
The debug output shows what I am trying to pass, but nothing goes into the database

Here is the full code

```
require_once (getcwd() . "/lib/dataLib.php");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
    {
        $projectName = $_POST['projectName'];
        $projectDescription = $_POST['projectDescription'];
        $projectLink = $_POST['projectLink'];
        addItemToDatabase($projectName, $projectDescription, $projectLink);
    }
}


/********************************
* addItemToDatabase
*******************************/
function addItemToDatabase($name, $description, $link)
{
$projectLinkSanSpace = str_replace(' ', '', $link);
$projectLinkAsLink = "<a href='project/" . $projectLinkSanSpace . "'>" . $link . "</a>";

databaseConnection('programWork');
$conn = new mysqli(DBF_SERVER, DBF_USER, DBF_PASSWORD, DBF_NAME);
if ($conn -> connect_error)
{
    die("Connection Failed!: " . $conn ->connect_error);
}
/*$sql = 'insert into projectList (
 *projectName, 
 *projectDescription, 
 *projectPage, 
 *projectSource) 
 *Values ("Stuff", "Things", "Yeah", "Yeah")'; */
$sql = "call insertItemIntoWork($name, $description, $projectLinkAsLink, $projectLinkAsLink)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
displayResult($result, $sql);
}
```

some notes on the code, 
I am using a lib to call external functions which I did not copy/paste here, as I do not think they are relevant to the question. I also did not include the HTML bits which is just the form which should be fairly straight forward, and should work since the debug *displayResults()* shows values.

Bottom line question is, is there something procedural that I am screwing up here. I do not have to call a function I suppose but is this a situation where the variables are set *after* the query is ran?

UPDATE
I added an error handler per Jay below:

```
$echoSuccess = true;
$msg = "The query completed successfully";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    if ($echoSuccess)
    {
        echo "<span class='errMsg'>" . $msg . " successful.</span><br />";
    }
} else
{
    echo "<strong>Error when: " . $msg . "</strong> using SQL: " . $sql . "<br />" . $conn->error;
    //displayResult($result, $sql)
}
```

Saying there are errors in my SQL. 
I think I can work those out and on account of that I do not think this question needs further answering, but rather illustrates the need of error handlers

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: @JayBlanchard, the SQL logs or the page logs? Inspecting in chrome shows no errors, there are no logs for the SQL on account of the query not reaching the database.

I do not have a logger of sort, I do not believe, setup.

Comment: Chrome dev tools is for Javascript. For PHP errors you need the web server's error logs.

Comment: I am using ampps to develope locally before I push to the webserver. The ampps error log shows blank (so no errors?)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Add error checking to your queries and database connection.

Comment: Ok, I think I have discovered the issue, will update my question I think if I work through it.

Answer (score 0):

So,
Thank you Jay Blanchard for pointing me in the right direction, turns out the spaces in my input were causing issues entering items into the database.
To fix this I had to add quotes around my parameters, though this seems like an odd requirement (perhaps I am missing something)
But it works now as expected.
Here are the alterations:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include "lib/style.php";
require_once (getcwd() . "/lib/coleSterlingLib.php");
//require_once (getcwd() . "/lib/jsFormInteraction.js");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
    {
        $projectName = $_POST['projectName'];
        $projectName = "'" . $projectName . "'";
        $projectDescription = $_POST['projectDescription'];
        $projectDescription = "'" . $projectDescription . "'";
        $projectLink = $_POST['projectLink'];
        $projectLink = "'" . $projectLink . "'";
        addItemToDatabase($projectName, $projectDescription, $projectLink);
    }
}
```

Note the `$projectName = "'" . $projectName . "'";`

Everything else stayed roughly the same

```
function addItemToDatabase($name, $description, $link)
{
$projectLinkSanSpace = str_replace(' ', '', $link);
$projectLinkAsLink = "<a href='project/" . $projectLinkSanSpace . "'>" . $link . "</a>";

databaseConnection('programWork');
$conn = new mysqli(DBF_SERVER, DBF_USER, DBF_PASSWORD, DBF_NAME);
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection Failed!: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//$sql = 'insert into projectList (projectName, projectDescription, projectPage, projectSource) Values ("Stuff", "Things", "Yeah", "Yeah")';
$sql = "call insertItemIntoWork($name, $description, $link, $link)";
//$result = $conn->query($sql);
$echoSuccess = true;
$msg = "The query completed successfully";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    if ($echoSuccess)
    {
        echo "<span class='errMsg'>" . $msg . " successful.</span><br />";
    }
} else
{
    echo "<strong>Error when: " . $msg . "</strong> using SQL: " . $sql . "
<br />" . $conn->error;
    //displayResult($result, $sql)
}
}
```